# Javascript functiion not working as expected

Tags: javascript

Currently I'm trying create a script that will only allow A-Za-z, 0-9, white space and comma. Here is my script:

```
<textarea name="commentText" onkeypress="return filterCharAll(event,this);"></textarea>
```

```
function filterCharAll(e, t) {
    if (window.event) {
        var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
    }
    else if (e) {
        var charCode = e.which;
    }
    else { return true; }
    if ((charCode > 47 && charCode < 58) || (charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123) || (charCode == 188 || charCode == 32 || charCode == 13)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }   
}
```

Everything is working perfectly! But the *comma* is not working. When I press it, nothing happens

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mek7qy8h/

Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: https://keycode.info/ when I test at this site, is showing 188 for comma. Anyways, 42 is not working too...

Comment: Regarding `if (window.event)`, the relevant event object is passed in the call, you don't need to look for it again. [*KeyboardEvent.keyCode*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) is deprecated and is from an obsolete standard, you should not use it, "*Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the `charCode` of `44` to match the comma:

```js
function filterCharAll(e, t) {
  if (window.event) {
    var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
  } else if (e) {
    var charCode = e.which;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
  if (charCode === 44 || (charCode > 47 && charCode < 58) || (charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123) || (charCode == 188 || charCode == 32 || charCode == 13)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea name="commentText" onkeypress="return filterCharAll(event,this);"></textarea>
```

But it might be easier to use a regular expression and test `e.key`:

```js
function filterCharAll(e) {
  return /[a-z0-9\s,]/i.test(e.key);
  // return true if the key is alphabetical (lower or upper),
  // or digits, or whitespace, or a comma
  // return false otherwise
}
```

```html
<textarea name="commentText" onkeypress="return filterCharAll(event);" onpaste="return false;"></textarea>
```

Another option that doesn't break pasting would be to use an `input` listener instead, and replace all disallowed characters with the empty string:

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
textarea.addEventListener('input', () => {
  textarea.value = textarea.value.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s,]/gi, '');
});
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `.key` since it will return the name of a special key, e.g. "Alt" which will match the regular expression without `^$` anchors.

Comment: Do you know how to avoid CTRL+V? Is possible insert certain characters using CTRL+V inside textarea

Comment: @inukix You can just `return false` on a `paste` event

Comment: But it will block paste on every box on my page? I need only inside this specfic textarea.

Comment: @inukix See the code in the answer - just like you can `onkeypress="return filterCharAll(event);"` for just that element, you can similarly `onpaste="return false;"` for just that element (paste would only be disabled on outer elements as well if the handler was attached to some outer element)

Comment: @CertainPerformance—please don't suggest breaking default UI features for the sake of very dubious additional annoyance.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using `charCode` since it is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress#Properties), instead you can use `char` and test that against a regular expression.

```
function filterAll(event) {
  return /[A-Za-z0-9, ]/.test(event.char);
}
```